# Rest controller - Tyr to reduce the number of endpoint with parameters but get Ambiguous mapping error

Tags: java, spring, rest, controller

I want to implement some simple endpoint in spring, trying to be as much Restful as possible and reduce the number of URL to use. Here are the GET url I want to call: (this is a simplified version)

```
GET /users
GET /users?id=123
GET /users?username=xyz
```

I used this controller:

```
@GetMapping()
public @ResponseBody
OutputUserDTO getUserByParameter(@RequestParam(required = false) String id,
                                 @RequestParam(required = false) String username) {
    if (id != null && !id.isEmpty()) {
        return userService.getUserById(id);
    }
    if (username != null && !username.isEmpty()) {
        return userService.getUserByUsername(username);
    }

    throw new MissingParameterException("...some message...");
}

@GetMapping()
public @ResponseBody
List<OutputUserDTO> getUsers() {
    return userService.getUsers();
}
```

Of course I get an error, that is **Ambiguous mapping**.

I thought to always return a List so that I can merge the 2 endpoints and, in case you pass some parameters, return a Singleton... even though I don't know if it's a correct practice. 
Or else, create one endpoint for each parameter, GET /users/{userId}, GET /users/{username}, ... but I don't like it neither (If I have 10 different way to get a user then I'll have to implement 10 endpoints :S)

What are some good practices in this case?? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `MissingParameterException` with `return userService.getUsers();`, and get rid of the other method, you know, the one with exactly the same mapping as the first method.

To make that work, you'd have to change return type to Object, which is not going to be a problem, since it's the actual object returned that controls the effect of `@ResponseBody`, not the declared type.

```java
@GetMapping()
@ResponseBody
public Object getUserByParameter(@RequestParam(required = false) String id,
                                 @RequestParam(required = false) String username) {
    if (id != null && ! id.isEmpty()) {
        return userService.getUserById(id);
    }
    if (username != null && ! username.isEmpty()) {
        return userService.getUserByUsername(username);
    }
    return userService.getUsers();
}
```

---

*FYI:* [`@ResponseBody`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html) is a method-level annotation, so it *should* be listed before any keyword modifiers.

The Java Language Specification, section [8.3.1. Field Modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1), says:

> *FieldModifier:*
>      *(one of)*
>      [Annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-9.html#jls-Annotation) `public` `protected` `private`
>      `static` `final` `transient` `volatile`
>
> [...]
>
> If two or more (distinct) field modifiers appear in a field declaration, it is customary, though not required, that they appear in the **order consistent with that shown above** in the production for FieldModifier.

Comment: Then you have to go through the following link http://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/pathvariable-spring-mvc/

Comment: @shubhendrasen Why would I read through a guide on `@PathVariable` when the code isn't using path variables?

Comment: @RequestMapping("users")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
 
    @GetMapping(path = "/{userId}", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public UserRest getUser(@PathVariable String userId) {

Comment: @shubhendrasen What's that for? OP is not trying to get a `/users/123` URL to work, but a `/users?id=123`. *Read the question again!*

Comment: If you have multiple getMappings for one url then you will get this exception . Both cannot be differentiated on the basis if what you send in your url. You have to specify a value in @getmapping.

Comment: @shubhendrasen Which is why my solution is to **only have one method**, and hence only one `@GetMapping`. *Read my answer again!!*

Comment: @Andreas my only concern is that in this case swagger don't display a response model example any more or if someone else wants to use the api doesn't know what's the return value without checking the internal implementation of thee service.

Comment: @Peppe That's not a problem caused by this solution, but a problem caused by your desire for multiple types of return values on a single `/users` endpoint, combined with using Swagger. Since there is no mention of Swagger in the question, this is a perfectly valid solution for the problem posed in the question. As the question is posed, you want 3 different "endpoints" that only differ by the query parameters passed. That can be done, and well documented. Whether Swagger can handle it or not, is a limitation of Swagger. Spring can handle it, as shown here.

Answer (score -1):

It should be like @GetMapping("/users") on respective method

http://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/pathvariable-spring-mvc/

Comment: Not if there is a `@RequestMapping("/users")` on the class itself.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that the reason for that is, in getUserByParameter, both parameters are optional but if both the parameters are not passed it will conflict with your second getMapping.

more over, what is returned changes in the three scenarios. scenario 1 returns a list of DTOs while scenarios 2 & 3 return  a single DTO

i dont think you can handle all three scenarios using your request path /users unless you want to wrap even a single DTO in a list, in which case you can simply merge your two methods. call getUsers() when both parameters are missing, in other cases, do what you currently do but wrap the response in a list.

if you want to keep them separate and return DTO or List, you should probably separate them out into /users and /user by specifying @GetMapping("/user") on method  one and @GetMapping("/users") on method two

hope this helps

Comment: *"i dont think you can handle all three scenarios"* Sure you can, just use `Object` as the return type. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58890443/5221149).

Comment: The API is that there are 3 URLs, which needs to be independently documented. The fact that the controller *implements* all 3 with a single method is an implementation detail, and doesn't affect the API or the API doc.

Comment: An API returning Object class is an anti pattern.  There is no good reason for doing this.  By using a proper domain class or dto you are communicating to your consumers what they can expect in response.  By returning an Object you are asking the consumer to keep guessing.  Today you may return a User, tomorrow a Giraffe and the day after a Pineapple.  That is not how APIs work in a sane world

Comment: The **API** is not returning `Object`. The Spring Controller method **implementing** the API is simply not *declaring* what it is returning, but it is returning one of two well-defined values: `OutputUserDTO` or `List<OutputUserDTO>`. The single **implementation** method is implementing **three** API methods. Do not confuse the implementation and the API. The Controller is *not* the API, it is an implementation *of* the API. The consumer doesn't have to guess anything, because the consumer shouldn't even know about the implementation, only the API. That's the entire *point* of APIs.

Comment: Whether the REST API is implemented by Java Spring, Ruby Grape, ASP.NET, or something else is entirely besides the point. The implementation doesn't define the API, the API defines the *contract* that the implementation must follow. The single-method solution given in the other answer is a perfectly valid implementation of the API defined in the question, i.e. the 3 endpoints `GET /users`, `GET /users?id=123`, and `GET /users?username=xyz`, with their associated return value.